# Https with Tcplistener

Tags: c#, ssl, https, tcplistener

I am building an application that can receive requests from a website to perform functionality not available in a browser. I accomplished this using a Tcplistener and then call in to it by performing ajax calls with jquery using jsonp. This is fine and works well, the problem now however is that the website also has to be able to use HTTPS, this results in a warning when making ajax calls that are not encrypted which is not desirable.

Is it possible to use https to make calls to my application without having a certificate registered on the users pc, as my application is I guess the server.

I hope that makes sense and I am not being stupid.

Many Thanks

Comment: It is not very clear to me if your application (acting as a server) communicates with some website or with clients(browsers) directly or with both. The basic idea is that if you use HTTPS to secure the communication, the software acting as client must trust the certificate that it receives from the server software in order to establish the secured SSL connection successfully. Now if you receive warnings on the browser then either the browser does not validates the certificate installed of the web server or you receive some content from the page over http not https.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for C# .NET

For HTTPS calls, the example is provided on MSDN using TCP Listner and TCP Client.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#Anchor_5

When doing sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, ..) you should load a PFX file along with password, instead of CER file, then it will not require registration on client machine.